# Get list of Group Matches

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have html example

```
<a href="http://page.extension?querystrings" class="same-class">CONTENT1</a>
<a href="http://page.extension?querystrings" class="same-class">CONTENT2</a>
```

I tried some different regex matching in order to get all CONTENTs.
I have managed to make a match at:
https://regex101.com
This is returning only the first match.
But even this is not working in C#

I have this code:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(html, @"andOfQS"" class=""same-class"">(.*)<\/a>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase & RegexOptions.Multiline);
    foreach (Match match in matches) {
    }
```

But, it return 0 matches.
Please help me to get all CONTENTs (1 to n).

Comment: You might try [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<a.*?class="same-class">(.*)<\/a>`

Code:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(html, @"<a.*?class=""same-class"">(.*)<\/a>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase & RegexOptions.Multiline);
    foreach (Match match in matches) {
    }
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dQ4kQ9/2)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the chance. It was my bad. When I checked the html, it was from the source code from the browser. When I ran the code, it was the html from the WinForms's WebBrowser. HTML was not the same at all. I found my solution.